# Office 365 Javascript Add-In - Speech Synthesis

Tags: javascript, ms-word, office-js

I'm currently working on a Word Add-In using the Office Tools for Visual Studio, which I want to implement TTS into.  As it is a web app, is it possible to use a Web speech API such as SpeechSynthesis, rather than a thirdparty solution?

I imagine this would work for platforms such as Word Online, but would it be possible for the desktop app?

Comment: Most browsers support one or another version of Speech Synthesis. Have a look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/speechSynthesis

Comment: I understand this but a word add-in is hosted locally.  I don't have a great understanding of exactly how it is hosted, but in the desktop app how would this work?

Answer (score 0):

You'll run into issues on the Windows versions of Word. Under the covers the new app platform use Internet Explorer as their engine (on windows, safari for mac/ipad).  Per the mozilla documentation there is no support for the speech synth api in internet explorer.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/speechSynthesis